# values for DropDownList items

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have follwoing code

```
@Html.DropDownList("optionsforuser", new SelectList(new[] { "Option1", "Option2", "Option3" }), "Select")
```

Is there anyway to initialize a value of 100 for Option1, 200 for Option2, 250 for Option3 etc within SelectList?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this Extension:

```
@Html.DropDownList("optionsforuser", 
    new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, int> 
        {
            {"Option1", 100},
            {"Option2", 200},
            {"Option3", 250}
        },
        "Value", "Key")
)
```

and pass it a `Dictionary<string, int>` with the dataValueField and dataTextField populated with your values and text

---

[SelectExtensions.DropDownList Method (HtmlHelper, String, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492738.aspx)

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList
)
```

---

[SelectList Constructor (IEnumerable, String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286.aspx)

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For situations where I just want to hard-code select list items (i.e. not get them from some pre-defined collection), I use this handy little class:

```
public class BetterSelectList : List<SelectListItem>
{
    public void Add(string text, object value, bool selected = false) {
        this.Add(new SelectListItem {
            Text = text, 
            Value = value.ToString(), 
            Selected = selected
        });
    }
}
```

Why is it "better"? It implements `IEnumerable` and has a multi-parameter `Add` method, which is all you need for the C# compiler to allow you to use [dictionary-style initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx), resulting in about the most noise-free initialization possible:

```
var optionsForUser = new BetterSelectList {
    { "Option1", 100, true },
    { "Option2", 200 },
    { "Option3", 250 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you set text and value

```
var selections = new List<SelectListItem>();
selections.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option1", Value = "100" });
selections.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Option2", Value ="200" });
```

Here is an MSDN article on select lists: [select list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your view like that as the others have posted, but can't you do it in the controller instead?

For example, In your view **model**:

```
public class ViewModel()
{
    public List<SelectListItem> OptionsForUser{ get; set; }
}
```

In your **controller**:

```
var optionsForUser = new List<SelectListItem>();
optionsForUser.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Option1", Value = "100"});
optionsForUser.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Option2", Value = "200"});
optionsForUser.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Option3", Value = "250"});

var viewmodel = new ViewModel();
viewmodel.OptionsForUser = optionsForUser;
return view(viewmodel);
```

then in your **view**:

```
@Html.DropDownList("optionsforuser", Model.OptionsForUser);
```

Those other solutions will work too, I just think its not very "clean" to initialise your dropdown list in your view like that. But its probably a matter of taste

Comment: Ron, its a good idea but i have to add that code in the master page. Is it good idea to do this via controller in master page?

Comment: Oh its for the master page.. Well, in that case, not really I guess. If you want to do it in your master page, you'll have to inherent all your controllers that use that master page from a base controller and then put that optionsForUser object into the viewbag. I guess just doing it in the view directly would be easier